# How to specify file mask for listdir and get methods of SFTPClient

Tags: python, paramiko

I want to do something like:

```
sftp.listdir("path_to_files/*.csv")
```

and similarly

```
sftp.get("path_to_files/*.csv")
```

Is it possible using `paramiko`?

thanks

Sonal

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty easy with list comprehensions

```
[ f for f in sftp.listdir("path_to_files") if f.endswith(".csv") ]
```